# Nabla operator in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, operator-theory

I am a little confused about the nabla oprerator as in complex analysis there is an operator which is defined as $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.However isn't the nabla operator supposed to be the one which is defined in the "classic" way in vector calculus? Is it just a complex operator which because it happens to be similar to the vector one we decide to  symbolize it in the same way?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) - your $\nabla$ is equal to Wirtinger's $2\frac{\mathrm{d}\overline{z}}{\mathrm{d}z}$ operator, which is identically zero for holomorphic functions